# Why is my mouse button not registering in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a button in pygame where if I press down, something happens. This works, but only after I click the mouse about 5-10 times. It may be because I'm using the mouse on my computer and not an external mouse. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```py
def button(x, y, width, height, ic, ac, action=None):

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    # print(mouse)

    if x + width > mouse[0] > x and y + height > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x, y, width, height), 0)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and action is not None:
                if action == 'play':
                    game_loop()
                elif action == 'quit':
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x, y, width, height), 0)
```

Comment: Do you mean a trackpad for the "mouse on my computer"?

Comment: How many `pygame.event.get()` calls do you've in your program?

Comment: @ DaveStSomeWhere Yes

Comment: @ Rabbid76 A lot. Does that jumble up the program?

Comment: @Blazian444 `pygame.event.get()` removes the events from the loop. Call it once per frame and use the list  of events in all your functions. See the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) gets all the messages from the event queue and remove them from the queue.
If you don't want to miss any message, then it is important to call `pygame.event.get()` only once in the application loop.

Get the events in the main loop and pass the list of events to `button()`, to solve the issue:

```py
def button(events, x, y, width, height, ic, ac, action=None):

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    # print(mouse)

    if x + width > mouse[0] > x and y + height > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x, y, width, height), 0)
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and action is not None:
                if action == 'play':
                    game_loop()
                elif action == 'quit':
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x, y, width, height), 0)


while True:

    events = pygame.event.get()


    # [...]

    button(events, .....)

    # [...]

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I've done that but now it says: "TypeError: 'Event' object is not iterable

Comment: @Blazian444 Sorry, but I can't "see" your code. Obviously you did it wrong. DO you pass a single event to the function or the list of events? If you pass a single event to the function, then you don't need the event loop in the function (`for event in events:`)